# All Paths from [Tiered] Non-Binary Tree

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries describing a tree, for example:

```
tree = [{(1,0): [(1,0), (1,1), (1,2)], 
         (1,3): [(1,3), (1,4), (1,5)]},
        {(1,0): [(2,0)],
         (1,1): [(2,1)],
         (1,2): [(2,2)],
         (1,3): [(2,0)],
         (1,4): [(2,1)],
         (1,5): [(2,2)]},
        {(2,0): [(1,0), (1,3)], 
         (2,1): [(1,1), (1,4)], 
         (2,2): [(1,2), (1,5)]}
       ]
```

Each row is a dict containing next branches. Keys of the dict in the first row are the roots, with subsequent rows containing the next possible nodes.

I'd like to create a list [of lists] containing all possible paths, e.g.:

```
[[(1,0), (1,0), (2,0), (1,0)],
 [(1,0), (1,0), (2,0), (1,3)],
 [(1,0), (1,1), (2,1), (1,1)],
 [(1,0), (1,1), (2,1), (1,4)],
 ...
 ...
 [(1,3), (1,5), (2,2), (1,2)],
 [(1,3), (1,5), (2,2), (1,5)]]
```

While there are many SO examples on using recursion/generators for binary trees, or non-binary [but using nested dictionaries], I can't find a proper way to do this in a case where the tree is described as above. Also, using [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/), and all_simple_paths doesn't preserve the tiered nature of the tree, and is therefore broken for this application.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following recursive generator function will do:

```
def paths(tree, node=None):
    if not tree or (node and node not in tree[0]):
        yield [node] if node else []
        return
    d = tree[0]
    nodes = [node] if node else d.keys()
    for node in nodes:
        for child in d[node]:
            for path in paths(tree[1:], node=child):
                yield [node] + path

>>> list(paths(tree))
[[(1, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (1, 0)],
 [(1, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (1, 3)],
 [(1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1)],
 [(1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (1, 4)],
 [(1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 2), (1, 2)],
 [(1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 2), (1, 5)],
 [(1, 3), (1, 3), (2, 0), (1, 0)],
 [(1, 3), (1, 3), (2, 0), (1, 3)],
 [(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (1, 1)],
 [(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (1, 4)],
 [(1, 3), (1, 5), (2, 2), (1, 2)],
 [(1, 3), (1, 5), (2, 2), (1, 5)]]
```